# Discrete Math Recurrence Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence and appropriate initial conditions for the number of binary strings of
length $n$ in which every $0$ is immediately preceded or followed by another $0$, but not both.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you have the recursion, what's the problem?

Comment: i only know that formula, but I am not sure how to actually apply it to this situation.

Comment: I don't understand.  The problem is to find the recurrence, and you have done that.  What else is there to do?  Surely the initial conditions are clear?  You just need to compute $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: Actually, your recursion is wrong.  It is easy to see that $a_1=1,a_2=2, a_3=3$  so you predict that $a_4=3+2=5$ but the only good sequences are $1111,1100,1001,0011$ so in fact $a_4=4$.  Do you agree with that?  How did you get the recursion you claim?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I found the recursion when in reality I was just confusing myself even more. I edited the post though.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C6%2C9%2C13&sort=&language=&go=Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us call such a sequence "good" and let $a_n$ denote their number.

Clearly any good sequence ends either in $1$ or in $00$.  Let $b_n$ denote the number of good sequences that end in $1$ and let $c_n$ denote the number of good sequences that end in $00$.  We remark that $$a_n=b_n+c_n$$

We can always append a $1$ to any good sequence so: $$b_n=a_{n-1}$$  We can only append $00$ to good sequences that end in $1$ so $$c_n=b_{n-2}=a_{n-3}$$

Thus $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the first few instances of all words of that length and the number of words matching the condition:

$n=1$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
w & \# \\
\hline
0 & - \\
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

$n=2$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
w & \# \\
\hline
00 & 1 \\
01 & - \\ 
10 & - \\
11 & 2 \\
\end{array}
$$

$n=3$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
w & \# \\
\hline
000 & - \\
001 & 1 \\ 
010 & - \\
011 & - \\
100 & 2 \\
101 & - \\
110 & - \\
111 & 3
\end{array}
$$

$n=4$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
w & \# \\
\hline
0000 & - \\
0001 & - \\ 
0010 & - \\
0011 & 1 \\
0100 & - \\
0101 & - \\
0110 & - \\
0111 & - \\
1000 & - \\
1001 & 2 \\ 
1010 & - \\
1011 & - \\
1100 & 3 \\
1101 & - \\
1110 & - \\
1111 & 4
\end{array}
$$

$n=5$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
w & \# \\
\hline
00000 & - \\
00001 & - \\ 
00010 & - \\
00011 & - \\
00100 & 1 \\
00101 & - \\
00110 & - \\
00111 & 2 \\
01000 & - \\
01001 & - \\ 
01010 & - \\
01011 & - \\
01100 & - \\
01101 & - \\
01110 & - \\
01111 & - \\
10000 & - \\
10001 & - \\ 
10010 & - \\
10011 & 3 \\
10100 & - \\
10101 & - \\
10110 & - \\
10111 & - \\
11000 & - \\
11001 & 4 \\ 
11010 & - \\
11011 & - \\
11100 & 5 \\
11101 & - \\
11110 & - \\
11111 & 6 \\
\end{array}
$$

And indeed (lulu beat me by 1 min) the case $n=4$ does not agree with your recurrence relation.

We see that all $0$ symbols, if showing up at all, must show up in pairs $00$ isolated by $1$s.